How do I collect water for the "elixir of life" quest?
In "Eastshade" (PC, via Steam), I have received the quest "The Elixir Of Life". Zahra has asked me to collect samples of water from each of the hot springs:

I've gone to the one hot spring I've found so far, on the Saltspring Coast, but I can't figure out how to actually collect the water.
As I approach the hot spring, the only action I have available is to "sit" -- which gave me inspiration the first time I did it but if I do it now I just crouch for a bit.

How do I collect the water for this quest?
